# Custom integration test in Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, integration-testing

For my application I wrote a custom integration test that starts the application, performs important functionality and tests many calculations. The test is part of the application's source control.

The details of every exception are written to the Trace or as an exception.

I would like to be able - on my Azure DevOps build server - to start this custom test after the build has finished.

I will adapt my test application then to mail the results to some developers.
For me this suits my needs better then test frameworks I have seen.

Currently I start Test in Debug Mode in Visual Studio (not integrated yet). It is a Console application, executed by 'Test.exe' on the command prompt. I will change that to Windows application (unattended execution, without console).

Question: how do I start my custom test on the Azure build server (who calls it Pipeline) after the build has finished? Which build step do I have to use?
Note that the integration test is also a build artifact of the same build.

Comment: Can you show us how you can call this test from console on your local machine?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej See my edit.

Comment: @Gerard Is your issue solved?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT I didn't have time to test it thoroughly as team opposes custom test ....

Comment: @Gerard If there is any update, kindly let us know.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends what external dependencies you have if you will be able to reach them from Azure DevOps agent but since you are on self hosted you have all cards in your hands. If this is Console app you can simply call it. Let's assume you copied it to `Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory` you can run it as:

```yaml
- pwsh: Test.exe
  workingDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

if you want to do as part of the same stage when you produced that file. If you want to make this in another stage then you need to first download [pipeline/build artifact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) and call it as above (you will get this probably in a different folder, so that needs to be changed).

Comment: Are you refering to YAML code with pwsh?
I see that I can add a task tot the pipeline (via web interface) that under 'utility' lists 'Azure DevOps - Azure Pipelines - Pipeline tasks - Utility tasks  Command line'.

Comment: Yeah (I haven't notice that you use classic pipeline, sorry), but this is almost the same. Select any console task like powershell, bash and just try run your exe file.